# When using Google Custom Search, page is blank

Tags: javascript, html

When I put my script code (html javascript) on my website, the page is blank and the google search bar is not there. I have set it up properly with the right website etc, but as soon as I go on the webiste it is still blank. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>******* - ************!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <script>
          (function() {
           var cx = '008901018504642689698:vb4c0smx720';
           var gcse = document.createElement('script');
           gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
           gcse.async = true;
           gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
           '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
           })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help

Comment: plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz Help

Comment: Do you get any console errors? The search engine id `cx` doesn't look quite right to me; have you copy-and-pasted it from the Google admin panel?